# ESLint spacing for typescript try/catch clause

Tags: typescript, try-catch, eslint

In typescript I have:

```
try {
}
catch(err) {
}
```

blocks and catch blocks without argument:

```
try {
}
catch {
}
```

In ESLint rules I have (edited extract from eslint.yaml):

```
space-before-function-paren: [error, {anonymous: never, named: never, asyncArrow: always}]
space-before-blocks: warn
keyword-spacing: [warn, {before: true, after: false, overrides: {catch: {after: true}}}]
```

With these rules, ESLint complains for the first try/catch block and not for the second one. If I remove the `keyword-spacing` overrides for `catch`, ESLint complains for the second block and not for the first one.

Do you know a magic combination of rules that suppress errors in both block types?

The workaround is, obviously, to stick a `// eslint-disable-line keyword-spacing` after the `catch(err) {` part, but I don't like this because this is an ad-hoc solution.

Thanks for teaching me!
mario