# ESLint rule conflicts for spacing in try/catch clause, typescript

Tags: typescript, try-catch, eslint, typescript-eslint

I have written a custom rule to enforce spacing in the catch block to follow the format below:

```
try {
} catch(err) {
}
```

And

```
try {
} catch {
}
```

My issue is that my `keyword-spacing` rule conflicts with my custom rule, complaining that the top block is incorrect when `"after": true` (default) and the bottom block is incorrect when `"after": false`. It works when the `keyword-spacing` rule is not active, but I need this rule for other keyword formatting.

I would like to know if there is any way I can ignore/override the `keyword-spacing` rule for catch blocks only?

`// eslint-disable-line keyword-spacing` is not a valid solution.

- I have tried changing the order of rules, it does not change anything.
- I have tried every combination of overrides in the `keyword-spacing` rule, but it only supplies `"after":true` or `"after":false`, both of which conflict.
- Disabling `keyword-spacing` fixes the catch conflicts, but I need this rule for other keyword formatting.

Thanks for the help,

Kyle

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59566195/eslint-spacing-for-typescript-try-catch-clause
This is someone else 3 years ago who had a very similar question with no response.